# Finding $f(x)$ from the functional equation $f(x)=x f\left(\frac{2x+3}{x-2}\right)+3$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find $f(x)$ if
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> x\cdot f\left(\frac{2x+3}{x-2}\right)+3 \ , &\text{if } x\ne 2\\ 
> 0 \ , &\text{if }x=2
> \end{cases} $$

No idea how to begin. I just noticed that $f(0)=3.$

Comment: That linear fractional transformation, applied twice, is the identity.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $$f(y)=yf(x)+3,$$where $y=\frac{2x+3}{x-2}$ and solve the system